# iPhone6 to iPhoneX: what happened to camera?

Tags: iphone, camera

Here's a video with iPhone6 and iPhoneX in a car.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sj4KBVI9K_U

Car engine is running.
On the right is iPhone6 - the camera feed is steady.
On the left is iPhoneX - notice the camera feed being all drunk and wavy.
As a result, photos, taken on the move, are nearly useless (very blurry) with iPhoneX.

This is a test on vibrations. If the iPhoneX is moved just 1mm so it's not touching the car, the wavy effect disappears.

What happened to the iPhone camera between 6 and X?
Can it be easily fixed?

As the primary need here was Mapillary images, also asked on the Mapillary forum, but no revelations so far.
https://forum.mapillary.com/t/iphone6-vx-iphonex-what-happened/5285

Comment: the phone on the left is demonstrating a classic example of electrical interference of some kind.

Comment: Either that and/or a faulty camera element. I think I remember some of the X's having faulty cameras when they where released

Comment: Why in heaven's name are you doing this in a car with all manner of other electronics running at the same time?  Does this happen at home, for instance?

Comment: This is a test on vibrations. If I move iPhoneX for 1mm so it does not touch the car anymore, the "drunkenness" disappears. Same effect observed in other locations in the car, so electric interference could be ruled out. Will state this explicitly in the description.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a metallic or magnetic case? If you are, try removing it and re-taking the video.

The parts used by the optical image stabilizer may interfere with the magnetic or metallic case, and can cause problems like this.

Answer (score -2):

[image]
From the image parameters, I think you can know the differences between iPhone 6S camera vs iPhone X camera quickly and directly.

Comment: How does this (even if it would be in english) explain the problem the OP experienced?